# Why do I get a ConcurrentModificationException even though I do not edit anything?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I am trying to convert some serial code into some 'nice' multithreaded code, but when I try to run it, I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` of the iterator from the point I get more than 200 elements in the `Set` I'm iterating over. I thought you could only get this exception if you tried modifying something you're trying to acces/iterate over or vice versa, but I am not changing anything.

The example I'm talking about iterates over the `keySet` of a `TreeMap` and the code looks as follows:

```
private static SortedMap<BigInteger,Long> algorithm7(int n, 
        final SortedMap<BigInteger, Long> S, ExecutorService pool) {

    final SortedMap<BigInteger,Long> S1 = new TreeMap<BigInteger, Long>();
    final SmallAntiChain alfa = SmallAntiChain.universeAntiChain(n);
    final SmallAntiChain u = SmallAntiChain.universeAntiChain(n+1);
    final SmallAntiChain l = SmallAntiChain.singletonAntiChain(n+1);

    Future<?>[] list = new Future[S.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (final BigInteger tCode : S.keySet()) {
        list[i++] = pool.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SmallAntiChain t = SmallAntiChain.decode(tCode);
                Set<int[]> rtsymm = (t.join(l)).symmetryGroup();
                SortedMap<BigInteger, Long> St = new TreeMap<BigInteger, Long>();
                for (SmallAntiChain x : new AntiChainInterval(t.join(l),u.omicron(t, alfa))) {
                    BigInteger b = x.standard(rtsymm).encode(); 
                    Storage.store(St, b);
                }
                for (BigInteger b : St.keySet()) {
                    SmallAntiChain x = SmallAntiChain.decode(b);
                    BigInteger code = x.standard().encode();
                    Storage.store(S1,code,St.get(b)*S.get(tCode));
                }
            }

        });
    }

    try {
        for(Future<?> f : list)
            f.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return S1;
}
```

with the calling method looking like:

```
public static SortedMap<BigInteger, Long>[] equivalenceClasses(int till, ExecutorService... pools) throws SyntaxErrorException {
    if(pools.length < 1)
        pools = new ExecutorService[]{ Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) };
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    SortedMap<BigInteger, Long>[] reS = new TreeMap[till+1];
    reS[0] = new TreeMap<BigInteger,Long>();
    Storage.store(reS[0],SmallAntiChain.emptyAntiChain().standard().encode());
    Storage.store(reS[0],SmallAntiChain.emptySetAntiChain().standard().encode());
    int n = 0;
    while (n < till) {
        reS[n+1] = algorithm7(n,reS[n], pools[0]);
        n++;
    }
    return reS;
}
```

Could anybody tell me **why** I get the exception and what I could do to solve this problem? Preferably without having to use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` or having to change anything in the signature.

Thanks in advance

---

**Edit:** completed code and added the calling method as well

Comment: What is `S1`? Please paste the full code

Comment: Possible solution: use a copy of the map in run() (e.g. ImmutableMap.copyOf(S)).

Comment: This will probably not solve your problem, but you can use an `ExecutorCompletionService` to track all submitted `Future` objects to that you don't have to maintain an array by your own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the issue hides in parts of the code that you didn't post. Maybe you're calling another method that modifies `S` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Java specification, `get(..)` should not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if the `SortedMap` has not been **structurally** modified. As you have not provided the full code, the only thing I can suggest is to wrap the `SortedMap` with `Collections.unmodifiableSortedMap(S s)` after you create it. This will throw an `Exception` if you have missed code that structurally modifies the Map.

Even if the code you provided does not modify the `SortedMap`, this doesn't exclude that an external(out of method)thread does not modify it.

Comment: The wrapper works, but would you coincidentally know where the exception might be coming from, provided the add-ons to the code?

Comment: If the wrapper works, this means that you are modifying the `SortedMap` outside of this method. Try wrapping it earlier at the point where you don't expect any more updates to flush out the thread that modifies it. It is always a good idea to use read-only structures in multi-threaded applications unless you use thread-safe structures.

Comment: I could move it all the way up to the initialisation of `reS` (after `Storage.store` of course) in `equivalenceClasses(...)` and even delete it again after having changed the initialisation of `reS` to be `reS = new SortedMap[till+1]` instead of `new TreeMap[till+1]`. Explanation is still welcome...